# Как закрыть командную строку после её вызова?

Tags: java, tomcat

Решил написать рестартер Tomcat'a. Но вот проблема, после вызова `shutdown.bat` и `startup.bat` консоли через которые я их вызвал не закрываются

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start "+tomcatPath+"\\bin\\shutdown.bat");

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start "+tomcatPath+"\\bin\\startup.bat");
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, может есть какой-то способ их закрывать, а то вручную это делать как то не очень.

Comment: в конце каждой команды дописать exit?

Answer (score 2):

Можно попытаться разобраться, что происходит во время выполнения команды `exec("cmd /c start "+tomcatPath+"\\bin\\shutdown.bat")`.

1. Запускается первый `cmd /c` в режиме завершения работы сразу после выполнения переданной ему команды
2. Он запускает в новом окне новый, второй `cmd`, но в режиме продолжения работы после выполнения команды
3. Последний исполняет shutdown.bat, который вызывает `call catalina.bat` в этом же интерпретаторе
4. `catalina.bat` выполняет что-то вроде `start java org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap stop`,
   т.е. открывает новое окно, в котором запускается java-приложение.
5. `catalina.bat`, не ожидая завершения java-приложения, продолжает выполнение.
   Но других команд нет, поэтому управление возвращается в `shutdown.bat`
6. `shutdown.bat` тоже на этом завершается, и управление возвращается во второй `cmd`,
   который ожидает от пользователя следующих команд. Вот оно, незакрытое окно.

Что тут можно сделать? Например, изменить режим запуска второго командного интерпретатора:
`"cmd /c start cmd /c "+tomcatPath+"\\bin\\shutdown.bat"`
В этом случае, завершив обработку `shutdown.bat`, `cmd` тоже закроется, и окошко исчезнет.

Можно отказаться от вызова первого интерпретатора:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(tomcatPath+"\\bin\\shutdown.bat").waitFor();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(tomcatPath+"\\bin\\startup.bat").waitFor();
```